# Not able to call the Content Block in a CloudPage using ampScirpt

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, content-builder, email-studio

In our email we have multiple content blocks and I am trying to call the content block within a cloud page using a simple AMPscript code something like below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

 %%= TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey("CONTENT_BLOCK_KEY")) =%%

  </body>
</html>
```

But I get an error page with status code 500

Could anyone tell me how to call a content block using AMPscript in a CloudPage? or any other way to resolve this easily?

Comment: Remove the spaces and try `%%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey("CONTENT_BLOCK_KEY"))=%%`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much..

Comment: what is the issue with spaces in cloudpage? But same code with spaces works in email

Comment: @JonasLamberty : You should add that as an answer (which hopefully the OP will select). That would be much better for future seekers/readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces and try

`%%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey("CONTENT_BLOCK_KEY"))=%%`

As to why your code works in emails, good question.
I've never tried this pattern with spaces, but they are definitely superfluous at best.